# Traversing prototype chain using constructor.prototype

Tags: javascript, constructor, prototype

If I can use `obj.constructor.prototype` to access the prototype of an object, then why can't I use `obj.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype` to traverse the prototype chain and have to use `Object.getPrototypeOf`?

```
function MyConstructor()
{
    this.prop = 1;
}

var o = new MyConstructor();

console.log(o.constructor.prototype) // MyConstructor

console.log(o.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype) // MyConstructor?
```

Shouldn't it return the prototype of MyConstructor which is `function() { [native code] }` (in Chrome console)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

All constructors are instances of the global `Function` object:

```
function Foo(){ this.x = 1 }; // Dummy constructor function

console.log(Foo instanceof Function) // => true; Foo is an instance of global Function constructor
```

All prototypes are instances of the global `Object` object:

```
console.log(Foo.prototype instanceof Object); // => true
```

When a constructor `Foo` is defined, it automatically has a `Foo.prototype` object attached to it, which you can think of as a "blank" object that itself, as per the above, inherits from the global `Object` object. In other words, the prototype of `Foo.prototype` is `Object.prototype`:

```
function Foo(){ this.x = 1 }; // Dummy constructor function

console.log(Foo.prototype); // Foo (object); already exists

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(Foo.prototype) === Object.prototype); // => true
```

Since `Foo.prototype` is a blank object, one would expect its constructor to be the global `Object` constructor function:

```
function Foo(){ this.x = 1 }; // Dummy constructor function

console.log(Foo.prototype.constructor) // => function Foo() { this.x = 1; } ??

console.log(Foo.prototype.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor); // => false
```

However this "blank" object has an explicit self-referential `constructor` property that points back to `function Foo(){ this.x = 1 }` and overwrites or "masks" the default constructor property you are expecting:

```
function Foo(){ this.x = 1 }; // Dummy constructor function

delete Foo.prototype.constructor; // Delete explicit constructor property

console.log(Foo.prototype.constructor) // => function Object() { [native code] }

console.log(Foo.prototype.constructor === Object.prototype.constructor); // => true
```

Therefore you can't use `obj.constructor.prototype` recursively to traverse the prototype chain and have to rely on the `Object.getPrototypeOf()` method.

Here's a great [visual reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYMyV.png).

Answer (score 2):

> If I can use obj.constructor.prototype to access the prototype of an object

You can't in general. Consider how this approach works:

```
var proto = MyConstructor.prototype;
// has an (nonenumberable) property "constructor"
proto.hasOwnProperty("constructor"); // `true`
// that points [back] to
proto.constructor; // `function MyConstructor() {…}`
```

As you see, that's a circular property structure. When you do

```
var o = new MyConstructor();
// and access
o.constructor; // `function MyConstructor() {…}`
// then it yields the value that is inherited from `proto`
// as `o` doesn't have that property itself:
o.hasOwnProperty("constructor"); // `false`
```

But that only works for object like `o` that inherit the `constructor` property from their prototype object and where that has a useful value with something pointing to the prototype object. Think of

```
var o = {};
o.constructor = {prototype: o};
```

Oops. Accessing `o.constructor.prototype` yields `o` itself here, and it could have been any other nonsensical value. The structure actually is the same as above with `MyConstructor.prototype` - and if you access `proto.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype[.constructor.prototype…]` you won't get anything else than just `proto`.

> then why can't I use `obj.constructor.prototype.constructor.prototype` to traverse the prototype chain and have to use `Object.getPrototypeOf`?

Because you're trapped in the circular structure as `MyConstructor.prototype`) has that `constructor` property itself and not inherited from `Object.prototype`. For really getting the next object the true prototype chain, you have to use `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

> ```
> var o = new MyConstructor();
> console.log(o.constructor.prototype) // MyConstructor
> ```

It should have been `MyConstructor.prototype` actually. Chrome console sometimes gets confused at displaying useful titles for unnamed objects though, and is not always correct.

If you get its prototype, it should yield `Object.prototype`, and when you get the prototype of the `MyConstructor` function itself it should be `Function.prototype`. Notice that you can do the latter by `MyConstructor.constructor.prototype` again…